# Re use existing Vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, discourse, vagrantfile

I have a Vagrant box for wordpress development already downloaded and provisioned, now I want to use a Vagrant box for Discourse, do I need to download Ubuntu again from the beginning and provision it?

Is there a way to use the existing box/vm without re downloading it again.

Comment: you can use the existing box in other directory, just set new directory by vagrant init dowloaded_box_name and vagrant up

Answer (score 1):

You should already have the original base box, it is stored in your `~/.vagrant.d/boxes`, you can list it using `vagrant box list`.

The one you are using is a spin-off from the base box, like a separate branch, you can view it in VirtualBox GUI and see this.

TO avoid starting from scratch, you can package the current wordpress box and use it as a new base box.

Package

`vagrant package --base name --output /path/to/name.box`

You can get it by using the following command:

```
$ VBoxManage list vms
"Windows XP" {fa768a76-5710-4b07-a4df-cc388370f038}
"archlinux" {c79dcee9-a523-4300-b026-cbc93ad37062}
"XenServer" {723b2acb-57cf-43ae-8202-f3a939924d20}
"Xen" {4491c002-51dc-40b8-941f-b6649b3b7d74}
```

Bitnami has pre-rolled Discourse Virtual Machine images (VMWare format), but it can be easily imported into VirtualBox, see this -> https://bitnami.com/stack/discourse